# Loop in arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

This is my `ArrayList`:

```
{10, 20, 30,40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100....1000}
```

I want to loop my result on button click.

I want first 5 results in first `Button`'s click.

Then automatically next 5 result likewise.

Is there any way I can do that?

```
for(int i=0 ;i<5; i++) {
   list = array.getJSONObject(i);
   fr.add(list.get("contact"));
 }
```

The problem is that I am only getting first 5 not next results.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: start iteration not from 0, but from `buttonClicks * 5`. End iterating not at 5, but at `buttonClicks * 5 + 5`

Comment: because you are looping only first five element

Comment: so what result do you expect from that ?

Comment: you need to remove the 5 first items from the arraylist after each time

Comment: @kouty yes sir how can I do that.

Comment: @Nolan check my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove first N items in an array list every time you call a method from index a to index b,

You can use `ArrayList.removeRange(int fromIndex, int toIndex)` every time you press that button (But don't iterate this )

or easily use `ArrayList.subList(start, end).clear();` for the same task!

> Removes from this list all of the elements whose index is between
>   fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. Shifts any succeeding
>   elements to the left (reduces their index). This call shortens the
>   list by (toIndex - fromIndex) elements. (If toIndex==fromIndex, this
>   operation has no effect.)

Read document > http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeRange%28int,%20int%29

example :

```
public void removeFistNItemsFromList(){

    for(int i=0 ;i<n; i++) {
     // add your items or do what ever you want!
    }
    myArray.subList(0, 4).clear(); // here from 0 to 4th index items will be removed and  list will be updated!
    System.out.println("MyArrayListNow:"+myArray);
}
```

output after each click :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are trying to reading first 5 elements always hence the problem. One option you have read and remove the elements from the arraylist. But a better approach would be to keep a count of mouse click, in which case it is a classic pagination problem, and u can fetch the next 5 elements and you will not lose the data in arraylist.